Comparison of ordinal numbers
I am studying Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin. This lemma is proved: let $f$ be an isomorphism of a well-ordered set $A$ onto some subset $B\subset A$. Then $f(a)\geq a$ for all $a \in A$. Then it is stated that this implites that two relations $\alpha=\beta$ and $\alpha<\beta$ are incompatible, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are types respectively of $M$ and $N$, two well-ordered sets.
I cannot work out how last statment is justified. Indeed lemma prove that $A$ cannot be isomorphic to any of its sections but I cannot see in this lemma the link between two different sets $M$ and $N$.

I don’t know the precise definitions being used here, but presumably if $\alpha=\beta$ and $\alpha<\beta$, you could compose the two maps to get an isomorphism of $N$ with one of its proper initial segments. (I.e. $M$ is both isomorphic to $N$ and to an initial segment of $N$ and you can compose one isomorphism with the inverse of the other.)

Specifically the contradiction in @spaceisdarkgreen's answer is then found by choosing the least element of $N-f(g^{-1}(N)$ lets say $x$, and noticing that by the lemma $f(g^{-1}(x))\ge x$ which is ofcourse untrue by $f(M)$ being an initial segment.
